# how to get list of sites/domains linked to in wireshark

Tags: debian, grep, regular-expression, wireshark, packet

I have been trying to figure out how many sites does firefox connect wth and for that have been using wireshark. What I have done is made a new profile and whenever I run firefox in the browser it is with

```
$ firefox --ProfileManager --safe-mode
```

Obviously before this command is run I run -

```
$ script

$ tshark -V -i wlan0
```

I set it by instructions from https://superuser.com/questions/319865/how-to-set-up-wireshark-to-run-without-root-on-debian

and had added myself to wireshark group.

So, what I did was run these three commands one after other -

```
$ script

$ tshark -V -i wlan0
```

and finally -

```
$ firefox --ProfileManager --safe-mode
```

The new tab/window opens and I'm able to capture the packets. Immediately after, I shut down the browser..

Now I need to grep through the packets. around 80 odd packets which came like -

```
Queries
        self-repair.mozilla.org: type A, class IN
```

which seems to be answered by the amazon domain -

```
Answers
        self-repair.mozilla.org: type CNAME, class IN, cname self-repair.r53-2.services.mozilla.com
            Name: self-repair.mozilla.org
            Type: CNAME (Canonical NAME for an alias) (5)
            Class: IN (0x0001)
            Time to live: 57
            Data length: 40
            CNAME: self-repair.r53-2.services.mozilla.com
        self-repair.r53-2.services.mozilla.com: type CNAME, class IN, cname shield-normandy-elb-prod-2099053585.us-west-2.elb.amazonaws.com
```

Is there a way to grep through the contents so that a list of domains which were touched can be known instead of trawling manually ?

Update - Did the -

```
$ tshark -V -i wlan0 -w trace1.pcap
```

Comment: Would not it been easier `sudo tdpdump -i  wlan0 port 53` or if you insist in seeing particular HTTP requests `sudo ngrep -d wlan0 "GET" "port 80"`?

Comment: I am not an expert but just learning things . Also it seems tdpdump doesn't seem to be packaged for debian, using existing tools.

Comment: `$ apt-file list tdpdump
$` As can be seen there is no output and I'm on Debian Stretch/testing. Aha, it seems you made a mistake, you meant `tcpdump` . I am open to using but you will need to share more details what ports are needed and how to go about doing that.

Comment: As I said. The full command is `sudo tcpdump -i wlan0 port 53` for listening to the DNS requests-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write the captured packet data into a file with the `-w` option and read it into `wireshark`, or capture directly in `wireshark`. Then select the *Request* item of the *HTTP* submenü in the *Statistics* menu.

Comment: Actually that didn't work. What I had done is renamed the typescript file to a-new-profile.txt file. I then tried to open the file in wireshark and it said it's a corrupt file even though I can read the file in any text-editor without any issues.

Comment: The typescript is decoded info for human consumption. What you need (and what `tshark -w <FILE>` produces) is the raw captured data in PCAP format. This is what you can read into `wireshark`.